# Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Byte was expected

Tags: casting, kotlin

I'm currently trying out kotlin, and I have a simple example here:

```
var byteToAdd: Byte = 3
var byteArray = byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
byteArray[0] += byteToAdd
println(byteArray[0])
```

But when executing, I get an error on line 3 because it says, that `byteToAdd` is an `Integer`, even though I set the type of `byteToAdd` to `Byte` on line 1.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line with the `+=` operator is equivalent to this longer call - you can actually convert between the two with intention actions in IntelliJ, if you invoke it on the operator:

```
byteArray[0] = byteArray[0].plus(byteToAdd)
```

The issue here is that the [`plus`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-byte/plus.html) operator you're calling on `Byte` is returning an `Int` (I'm assuming because there's no guarantee the result will fit in a `Byte`), which can't be implicitly converted back to `Byte` to be put back in the array.

You can fix this by using this longer syntax, *and* doing an additional conversion of the result back to `Byte`:

```
byteArray[0] = byteArray[0].plus(byteToAdd).toByte()
```